# Automapper - Using Resolver to map under condition

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

Defining a resolver as follows:

```
public string Resolve(AppUser source, MemberDto destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
{
    if (source.Photos.Count > 0)
    {
        if (source.Photos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsMain) != null)
        {
            var urlStart = (source.Photos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsMain).Url.ToString()).Substring(0, 4);
            if (urlStart == "http")
            {
                return source.Photos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsMain).Url;
            }
            else
            {
                return _config["ApiUrl"] + source.Photos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsMain).Url;
            }
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

and mapping the property as follows:

```
    CreateMap<AppUser, MemberDto>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Image, o => o.MapFrom<MemberAvatarResolver>())
```

and returning the result as follows:

```
public async Task<PagedList<MemberDto>> GetMembersAsync(UserParams userParams)
{
    var query = _context.Users
                    .Include(p => p.Photos)
                    .AsQueryable();

        var mappedEntity = query.ProjectTo<MemberDto>(_mapper
                        .ConfigurationProvider, new { Image = query.Select(u => u.Photos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsMain).Url)});

        return await PagedList<MemberDto>.CreateAsync(mappedEntity, 
                userParams.PageNumber, userParams.PageSize);
}
```

But I am getting a mapping exception:

> Unable to create a map expression
>
> Type Map configuration: AppUser -> MemberDto
>
> Destination Member: Image

I've found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62571951/auto-mapper-custom-resolver-source-members-to-destination-object-list-mapping-is) but it uses an anonymous type instead of DTO/Resolver

Any help on how to implement this case ?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#supported-mapping-options

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using: "ProjectTo". And that only works around Expressions.
What you want is **not supported**.

See documentation on: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#supported-mapping-options

**Supported mapping options**

Not all mapping options can be supported ........

Not supported:

- MapFrom (Func-based)

.......