# .Net Core web API Paged List - The provider for the source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

After got no answers for [my other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69662465/automapper-using-resolver-to-map-under-condition), I've made a different implementation, this time a Union of two Lists instead of the Automapper mapping projection.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MemberDto>>> GetMembersList([FromQuery] UserParams userParams)
{
    var members = await _unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetMembersAsync(userParams);

    Response.AddPaginationHeader(members.CurrentPage, members.PageSize,
        members.TotalCount, members.TotalPages);

    return Ok(members);
}
```

The repository:

```
    public async Task<PagedList<MemberDto>> GetMembersAsync(UserParams userParams)
    {
        var members1 = await _context.Users
        .Where(x => x.Photos.Any(y => y.Url.Substring(0, 4) == "http"))
            .Select(m => new MemberDto
            {
                Id = m.Id,
                UserName = m.UserName,
            }).ToListAsync();
    
        var member2 = await _context.Users
        .Where(x => x.Photos.Any(y => y.Url.Substring(0, 4) != "http"))
            .Select(m => new MemberDto
            {
                Id = m.Id,
                UserName = m.UserName,
            }).ToListAsync();
    
        var members = members1.Union(member2).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName).ToList();
        var query = members.AsQueryable();
query = query.Where(u => u.UserName == "John");
        return await PagedList<MemberDto>.CreateAsync(query, userParams.PageNumber, userParams.PageSize);
    }
```

And the paged list class:

```
public static async Task<PagedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageNumber, 
    int pageSize)
{
    var count = await source.CountAsync();
    var items = await source.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
    return new PagedList<T>(items, count, pageNumber, pageSize);
}
```

But when I send the request I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The provider for the source
> 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider'. Only providers
> that implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider' can be used for Entity Framework
> asynchronous operations.

Some answers in Stackoverflow provide a workaround using View() which is used for only for MVC.

Comment: `ToList().AsQueryable()` - this is no more EF Core queryable, hence the error message. Try removing all `ToList` / `ToListAsync` calls from the code.

Comment: @IvanStoev If I do that the query won't be translated.

Comment: If it can't be translated, then it can't be efficiently paginated (all the data is already loaded in memory). To do pagination in memory, create and use another non async `Create` method which takes `IEnumerable<T>` and uses sync LINQ to Objects methods (e.g. `source.Count()`) inside.

Comment: I've created the non async method, but it still cannot be translated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All EF Core async queryable extensions work only with EF Core `IQueryable` implementations. While `ToList()` loads all data in memory, and the `AsQueryable()` is LINQ to Objects `IQueryable` implementation which cannot be used with EF Core extenson methods.

So the solution is to remove all `ToList` / `await ToListAsync()` calls, thus keeping the result EF Core `IQueryable`.

The problem as I understand is that EF Core is unable to translate the query, so you are executing it and putting the result in memory. So this is a workaround, but then the query cannot be efficiently paginated server side, thus no need of async processing. What you should do is to create and use synchronous `Create` method overload like this

```cs
public static PagedList<T> Create(IEnumerable<T> source, int pageNumber, 
    int pageSize)
{
    var count = source.Count();
    var items = source.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    return new PagedList<T>(items, count, pageNumber, pageSize);
}
```

and modify the code to use it instead of `CreateAsync`

```cs
// original code...
var members = members1.Union(member2).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName).ToList();
var query = members //.AsQueryable() not needed anymore
    .Where(u => u.UserName == "John");
return PagedList<MemberDto>.Create(query, userParams.PageNumber, userParams.PageSize);
```

But this should be used only as last resort. Before doing that it's better to try make the EF Core query translatable. In this particular case I guess the problem is with `Union` operator (or something inside its parts), which with the sample could easily be eliminated (the `Union` looks unnecessary), but I guess that's not the real case. If you provide a more realistic example and well as the target EF Core version, we can take a look if something can be done (unfortunately EF Core query translation is still trial-and-error game).

Comment: I tried exactly what you suggested but the query still could not be translated, error message: "could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'."

Comment: Which query cannot be translated? The answer is based on your original code in the question where `members1` and `members2` are lists, i.e. already executed and materialized queries. Hence there is no query.

Comment: It is needed to keepToList / await ToListAsync() calls for members1 and members2 and then use the non async method to make it work.

Comment: Of course. I thought that was obvious - either keep all parts queryable and use `CreateAsync`, either use lists (keep the original approach) and use `Create` at the end.

Comment: only using lists for parts work, then in my original code I have "var query = members.AsQueryable();" to use it for e.g. "query = query.Where(u => u.UserName == "John");" if I use "return PagedList<MemberDto>.Create(query, userParams.PageNumber, userParams.PageSize);" it returns an empty result.

Comment: Look at the answer. `//...` means the original code up to the snippet starting with `var members = ...` and ending with `return ...`, which is the modification needed. There is no `query` variable there. I could have easily copy/pasting the whole original code and modify it, but that way the modification will be hidden inside.

Comment: I have updated the question to highlight the query variable which was in the original code. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Ah, so you just have `Where` which you skipped in the original post. No problem, just use LINQ to Objects (no need `AsQueryable()` anymore after getting the `members` list).

Comment: But note that it is better to apply such filters in advance, e.g. declare something like `var users = _context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == "John");` and use it in the original code in place of `_context.Users`. It would just make the operation more performant (will load less data in memory).

Comment: You're right, applying such filter in advance, and using ListAsync (the original approach), and use the non async "Create" method made it work fine, I guess this is the optimal solution.